# nestjs can't inject dependency in custom decorator

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, casl

In offical document about [authorization](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization), i follow this guide and use `casl` lib

Let's assume that if i want to validate the request man is the owner of an article, i must get the article data from the database, and compare `userId` between `user` and `article.userId`, so i must inject a repoistory dependency like this

```
@Injectable()
export class DeleteHolePolicyHandler implements IPolicyHandler {
  @Inject()
  private readonly treeholeDaoService: TreeholeDaoService

  async handle(ability: AppAbility, req: Request) {
    const hole = await this.treeholeDaoService.findById(req.body.id)

    return res
  }
}
```

but i got an error, it shows me `this.treeholeDaoService` is undefined.

so what should i do that can make it work?

this is [reproduce link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nestjs-typescript-starter-vyavzz?file=src%2Fpolice.guard.ts,src%2Fmodules%2Fcasl%2Fcasl.factory.ts,src%2Fpolice.ts,src%2Fcommon%2Fread.police.ts,src%2Fmodules%2Fcasl%2Fcasl.module.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp.controller.ts,src%2Fapp.service.ts&terminal=start)

Comment: Try add `constructor(@Inject(TreeholeDaoService)) private treeholeDaoService: TreeholeDaoService) {}`

Answer (score 2):

You can't inject dependencies since it's an in-place property declared using new. As stated in the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization):

> Since we must instantiate the policy handler in-place using the new keyword, `ReadArticlePolicyHandler` class cannot use the Dependency Injection. This can be addressed with the `ModuleRef#get` method (read more [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref)). Basically, instead of registering functions and instances through the `@CheckPolicies()` decorator, you must allow passing a `Type<IPolicyHandler>`. Then, inside your guard, you could retrieve an instance using a type reference: `moduleRef.get(YOUR_HANDLER_TYPE)` or even dynamically instantiate it using the ModuleRef#create method.

Comment: but if i want to throw some Exception like `throw new BadRequestException('you can't delete other's article')` in policeHandler, the global `HttpExceptionFilter` cannot catch this error, what should i do?

Comment: you can try getting moduleRef.get(HttpExceptionFilter) and manually trigger the method you want to be executed.